# Proxy auto detection in Linux using C

Tags: c, linux, proxy, static-libraries

I can detect the proxy setting in Windows using `WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser()` API, but in linux it seems that different linux distros employ different ways to store proxy settings and not all of them use `$http_proxy` environment variable which I previously thought. For instance, In ubuntu, google chrome picks proxy settings from gsettings. which is updated when we set proxy settings using gnome UI. Is there any library or something alike which can help detecting the system proxy settings of Linux irrespective of its flavor.

Comment: Different application may use http_proxy environment variable, different may not and use its own settings mechanism. Can you decide which one has more priority for you?

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler My application won't provide functionality to manually specify proxy settings, so I'll pick system one by default.